# microsoft dynamics crm 2011 change owner

Tags: windows, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have microsoft dynamics crm 2011 with rollup 16, and when trying to change your owner, for example, in the Sales - Work Orders ei nothing happens. Choose it from the list, and when I approve the owner does not change.

Please give me some advice what's wrong?

Comment: we just started having the same issue with reassigning records in CRM 2011 it appears to have recently started and 5 days ago we updated to Rollup 16
i am thinking about uninstalling rollup 16
TIm

Answer (score 1):

After escalating to Microsoft and providing them with a trace from the CRM Diag Tool. they had me recreate a function in SQL Server management studio\databases(ORG_Name)\programmability\functions\table-valued functions\dbo.fn_collectforcascadeassign

recreation was done by creating a second temp org and editing the same function to the original org pasting into a new query and running the query. (with no one in the system)

Hope it helps
TIm